# Is there a reactive function which executes and passes the original value?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a flow which transforms data, acts on it, transform it again, and acts on that. For example:

```
// Current code
Just(0)
    .map({ $0 + 1 })
    .map({ funcX($0); return $0 })
    .map({ $0 + 1 })
    .map({ funcY($0); return $0 })
    ...
```

I know reactive programming is about streams, but I would like to call `funcX` without needing to return the value. Is there a function which passes in the value and automatically passes along the value? Something like:

```
// Hypothetical
Just(0)
    .map({ $0 + 1 })
    .call({ funcX($0) })
    .map({ $0 + 1 })
    .call({ funcY($0) })
    ...
```

Note: The above swift needs more syntax to actually compile, just is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a custom operator, one already exists: `handleEvents`

```
Just(0)
    .map({ $0 + 1 })
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { funcX($0) })
    .map({ $0 + 1 })
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { funcY($0) })
    ...
```

The `handleEvents` operator can hook into any part of the publisher/subscriber lifecycle with it's optional parameters:

- receiveSubscription
- receiveRequest
- receiveCancel
- receiveOutput
- receiveCompletion

Comment: Great! I wish it was less verbose, like `call` above, but this is correct to me.
Since I posted the question I've been tweaking my flows. I still need map to handle a "previous/new" and pass on a mapped collection. I get the previous values from the a subject, then set the new values to that subject, and return a mapped collection for the next flow.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can write your own operator, but as for me there is simpler approach, based on default operators, having handler, eg:

> ```
> extension Publisher {
>
> /// Republishes all elements that match a provided closure.
> ///
> /// - Parameter isIncluded: A closure that takes one element and returns a Boolean value indicating whether to republish the element.
> /// - Returns: A publisher that republishes all elements that satisfy the closure.
> public func filter(_ isIncluded: @escaping (Self.Output) -> Bool) -> Publishers.Filter<Self>
> ```

so your case would look like

```
.filter({ funcX($0); return true })
```

as a result you have transparent stream and possibility to execute any callback on Downstream values.

You can even wrap it, like

```
extension Publisher {
    public func call(_ closure: @escaping (Self.Output) -> Void) -> Publishers.Filter<Self> {
        return self.filter({ closure($0); return true })
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking I'd need to create my own operator. Your wrapper is perfect!